# How to avoid multiple application instances?

Tags: c#, dll, mutex

I have an application, "myprogram.exe", which calls functions and code inside a dll, one of this functions that "myprogram.exe" calls create a new instance of a winform, "MyForm.cs" and then show it using form.show();.

I can have 'n' number of "myprogram.exe" instances running, but I want to have only one instance of "MyForm.cs" for each instance of "myprogram.exe".

The problem that I have is that even thought I'm using mutex inside "MyForm.cs" to create a mutex and them ask if an instance of it is already running, sometimes, it creates another instance, despite the mutex.

Is there another way that I can use to validate if an instance of "myprogram.exe" has already created an instance of "MyForm.cs".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c/229567 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex

Comment: I'd guess you're doing something wrong with the mutex; generally speaking, there would be Serious Problems if mutexes weren't doing their job.

Comment: This might be a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975250/reliably-detecting-that-another-of-my-applications-is-running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Joe's comment, the problem is likely to be in the implementation of the Mutux.

[This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975250/reliably-detecting-that-another-of-my-applications-is-running/975272#975272) demonstrates the right way to do it:

> K. Scott Allen has [a good write up](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/401.aspx) on using a Mutex for this purpose and issues you'll run into with the GC.
>
> > If I want to have only one instance of the application running across all sessions on the machine, I can put the named mutex into the global namespace with the prefix “Global\”.
> >
> > ```
> > [STAThread]
> > static void Main() 
> > {
> >    using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
> >    {
> >       if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
> >       {
> >          MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
> >          return;
> >       }
> >
> > Application.Run(new Form1());
> >    }
> > }
> > ```

Comment: Thanks. I was about to post a similar question and I found this answer extremely helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

I post below link, since I could not find any related article in C++ and MFC. Therefore,
For C++, MFC and Win32 you can use http://flounder.com/nomultiples.htm