# Maximize application in system tray?

Tags: c#, wpf, system-tray, application-singleton

I wrote a little WPF app that when 'closed' minimizes to the system tray (customer requirement).  Double clicking pops it back up, or right click gives a context menu to exit.

But if the app is minimized, and the users navigate to Start->All Programs->The Application it starts a new instance.

What (in C#) do I need to do to get the app to maximize the running instance if the user does this rather than fire up a new instance?

Thanks!

Comment: look up Mutex objects and grabbing a an active window. don't have the code in front of me, but it's the direction you need to take. -- I lied, try [this article on single instances of .net applications](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html)

Comment: @Nicros, hey did you get any solution for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975250/reliably-detecting-that-another-of-my-applications-is-running/975267#975267) from Jon Skeet discusses using a mutex to do it

> Mutex is the way to go. It's a lot
>   less fragile than using process names
>   etc.
>
> However, you need to make sure the
>   Mutex isn't garbage collected. In the
>   case of a service (which is event
>   driven rather than having a "main"
>   method which runs to completion), the
>   most sensible way of doing this is
>   probably to put it in a static
>   variable.
>
> Dispose of the mutex when the service
>   stops, so you don't need to wait for
>   finalization or anything like that.

Matthew Brindley gives this example in the same question for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975250/reliably-detecting-that-another-of-my-applications-is-running/975272#975272)

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
   using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
   {
      if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
         return;
      }

      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

To maximize the other application you'll need to send it the message to maximize. See this article on [message sending](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx)

Comment: Have to retract my Perfect! statement- this checks for the instance running and does not start a new one- but does not answer the question how to Maximize this system tray'ed application without starting a new instance.

Comment: Pfft.  Let me retract my retraction- missed the link at the bottom for messageing.. will check it out.