# Restore application from system tray when clicking on desktop shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms, system-tray

I've created an application that starts off in the system tray when it is started. I used the below post to achieve this:
[How to start WinForm app minimized to tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray)

This application also only allows a single instance to run:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/C-Single-Instance-App-With-the-Ability-To-Restore

The problem I'm getting is when I first start the application it minmizes to the  system tray, but if I click the desktop icon it does not appear. I have to click on the icon in the tray to restore the application. If I then minimize it again and then click on the desktop icon it appears.

This is my second attempt at a winform application, is it something to do with the SetVisibleCore?

Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611828/maximize-application-in-system-tray

Comment: I use the code from the two links above, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex/SingleInstanceMutexSampleV2.txt

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154693/activate-a-hidden-wpf-application-when-trying-to-run-a-second-instance, for a answer for WPF application

Answer (score 1):

If you make your WinForms application a singleton, then it is very easy to make the minimized window restore,

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx

It is just another variant of using WindowsFormsApplicationBase from Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices namespace. Easier/better than using a Mutex.

You might change

```
    void this_StartupNextInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = MainForm as Form1; //My derived form type
        form.LoadFile(e.CommandLine[1]);
    }
```

to

```
    void this_StartupNextInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = MainForm as Form1; //My derived form type
        form.Show();
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Comment: Hi,it's a Winform application?

Comment: Just tried the example given and it doesn't work at all when I click on my desktop icon, its still displayed in my system tray though. Would any of the code in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray cause any conflict?

Comment: You only need one of them. If you use WindowsFormsApplicationBase as I suggested, then please don't use any Mutex related trick.

Comment: I removed the mutex code in the static void Main() and used the example given and doesn't work in my scenario it doesn't work ie. When I first launch the application it starts it in the system tray. If I click on the desktop shortcut it does not maxmise it. If I double click on the icon in the system tray it maxmizes without any problem. If I the minmize to the system tray and then click on the desktop icon it opens ok. I think it's when it is first launched. I think something isn't registering.

Answer (score 0):

What if you write the restore logic in your main. You can do this by using [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) function and the `SW_MAXIMIZE` flag.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 9; //Command to restore the window

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        bool onlyInstance = false;
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "UniqueApplicationName", out onlyInstance);
        if (!onlyInstance) 
        {
             Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("UniqueApplicationName");
             SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
             ShowWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
             return;
        }
        Application.Run(new MainForm);
        GC.KeepAlive(mutex);
}
```